# Angular 13, I can't use interpolation to play youtube video

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm trying to use interpolation to play a youtube video, it's not working. The project object's video field is a string holding https://www.youtube.com/embed/nwNQexRDAf0 but for some reason it just appears as nothing. However, when I replace the {{product.video}} with "https://www.youtube.com/embed/nwNQexRDAf0", then the code runs like how I want it to.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src={{product.video}} title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How do I fix this, and why does this happen?

Comment: And what does network tab tries to load? Have you inspected final HTML?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you need to use domsanitizer for the url. https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrustresourceurl